# New 11" iPad Pro: Headphones Kraken USB

Tags: ipad, usb, headphones

I am trying to connect my 11" iPad Pro with my Razer Kraken USB headphones. I have a USB type A to type C adapter. The iPad powers up the headphones.

Sometimes the sound is perfectly fine (rarely), other time the sound is distorted. Also, some time I can't control the volume.

Any idea how can I connect them? Or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a new adapter as that could be faulty.

If that doesn’t work try resetting the iPad:

1. Press and hold the sleep/wake button and either volume buttons
2. Hold them top I’ll the Apple logo appears

If that doesn’t work try and see if the headphone wire/speaker works properly.

Comment: I tried my adapter in my samsung s8.. I also tried them in my laptop.it seems to work without any problem...
I tried restarting the ipad...sometimes it seems to work for some time and then suddenly stops.

Comment: Did you try resetting it like I mentioned?

Comment: Yeap...several times

Comment: I see, try to see if your headphones work correctly, possibly sending it in for a diagnostics